# How to change independently width and height of the text in ggplot (i.e. make "distorted" letters)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to draw consensus sequence (see image as an example). For this, I would need to adjust letters' height keeping the same width. Is there easy way to do this in R?
Thanks in advance.

[image: example]

Comment: Have a look at the [seqLogo package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/vignettes/seqLogo/inst/doc/seqLogo.pdf)

Comment: @Henrik, thank you very much! It seems to be the solution in my case. Although I am still curious is there any way to change letters' dimensions in general, so I'll leave the question open.

Comment: P.S. seqLogo package is available only through Bioconductor, right?

Comment: At least there, it seems: http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/seqLogo.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also interested in displaying distorted text and came across this page. Another [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211399/convert-textgrob-to-imagegrob-rastergrob) points to either 1) saving the text as an image and plotting with rasterGrob() or 2) using the grImport package and plotting using the grid package.

Those options both looked cumbersome to me so I was excited to see how the seqLogo package that Henrik mentioned in the comments handled this. However, while it is pretty clever for getting around saving to file, it is not really a general solution that can be applied elsewhere. Or at least for me, because I am using symbols other than A, T, C and G.

The seqLogo authors first **manually defined the shape of each letter**. For instance, here is the letter T:

```
letterT <- function(x.pos,y.pos,ht,wt,id=NULL){

  x <- c(0,10,10,6,6,4,4,0)
  y <- c(10,10,9,9,0,0,9,9)
  x <- 0.1*x
  y <- 0.1*y

  x <- x.pos + wt*x
  y <- y.pos + ht*y

  if (is.null(id)){
    id <- rep(1,8)
  }else{
    id <- rep(id,8)
  }

  fill <- "red"

  list(x=x,y=y,id=id,fill=fill)
}
```

You can see in the function signature that the shape is calculated dependent on ht and wt, the height and width, allowing the letters to be distorted. The letters are then **plotted using grid.polygon function**:

```
grid.polygon(x=unit(letters$x,"native"), y=unit(letters$y,"native"),
    id=letters$id,
    gp=gpar(fill=letters$fill,col="transparent"))
```

If you're only dealing with nucleotides -- or otherwise have some way of defining all the character shapes you intend to use -- I'd say this would be a great approach and much cleaner than saving a bunch of .png files and loading them.