# convert textGrob to imageGrob/rasterGrob?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

Apologies if this is very straightforward. Actually I hope it will be!

I am trying to dynamically create images from text which I can then resize and plot (either stretched or squashed) to produce a motif-type graph.

I started out using images (which I'd generated using `png()` and `ggplot()`) and plotting them as `annotation_custom()`

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
require(gridExtra)
qplot(c(0,10),c(0,10)) + 
annotation_custom(rasterGrob(image=readPNG("1999.png"),x=0,y=0,height=1,width=1,just=c("left","bottom")),
              xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=7.5)
```

to produce:

[image]

This is fine, but it's awkward to create the images dynamically if they are not the same size, using `png()`, plus it's clunky to persist them to file, so I tried to see if I could use a textGrob:

```
myText<-"1000"
myTextGrob<-textGrob(myText,just=c("left","bottom"),gp=gpar(fontsize="100",col="red",fontfamily="Showcard Gothic"))
qplot(c(0,10),c(0,10))+annotation_custom(myTextGrob,0,0,0,0)
```

and got this, which is fine, except....

[image: textGrob]

...it doesn't seem possible to stretch & skew it in the same way as a `rasterGrob` so my question is - is it possible to create the textGrob and coerce it to a rasterGrob? Or is there another solution which will let me skew/stretch the textGrob?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know there are some [motif packages on bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/search/index.html?q=motif). I haven't used them or checked their code...but maybe you can find something useful there. Cheers.

Comment: the grImports package offers some possibilities to draw vector graphics as grobs; maybe they can be scaled. There's a temporary xml-based representation of the vector shape, which may be useful to bypass the creation of an external file.

Comment: @baptiste - thanks I think that's what I'm looking for. I've been fiddling with PostScriptTrace, but struggling a bit on a Win64 laptop. Problem is I can't seem to find examples / specs for the xml/RGML representation. Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks! Troy.

Comment: not really, the only examples I know are in the vignette. My advice would be to contact the package authors directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem easy without creating temporary files. Instead of raster files, you might use vector paths with the grImport package. There are two options to import text,

- as a path; it works (example below), but there's no obvious way to bypass the ps to xml conversion step with intermediate files
- as a text string; the xml is much shorter in this case, and could be created directly from R, but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to transform the two axes independently.

---

```
library(grImport)

scale_text <- function(text="hello world", scale=4, tmp=tempfile()){
  tmp.ps <- paste0(tmp, ".ps")
  tmp.xml <- paste0(tmp, ".xml")
  string.ps <- paste0('%!PS
                    /Courier             % name the desired font
                    20 selectfont        % choose the size in points and establish 
                    % the font as the current one
                    1 ', scale, ' scale            % scale axis
                    72 500 moveto        % position the current point at 
                    % coordinates 72, 500 (the origin is at the 
                    % lower-left corner of the page)
                    (', text, ') show  % stroke the text in parentheses
                    showpage             % print all on the page
                    ')
  cat(string.ps, file=tmp.ps)
  PostScriptTrace(tmp.ps, tmp.xml)
  readPicture(tmp.xml)
}


hello <- scale_text()
grid.newpage()
grid.picture(hello)
```

[image]

Comment: actually, I suspect that there is no internal R graphics routine to distort text, in which case the call to ghostcript is really necessary to take care of this operation.

Comment: yes it seems to be the only way. The current release of GS doesn't support pswrite, so doesn't seem to be compatible with grImport. Any idea on whether you can force PostScriptTrace() to call a different -sDEVICE parameter?

Comment: maybe you can define your own function copying the code from PostScriptTrace and changing the body as appropriate

Comment: Hi @Baptiste - thanks for all your help on this. I think this is the only way to go. The grImport package at R-Forge has been updated to be compatible with GS9.10 via ps2write device, so now it works. Thanks, Troy.